# check if pushed tag is on the git remote

Tags: git

Anyone know how to check if a tag is on the git remote after the tag is pushed from the local?

It seems that the only way to do it is to fetch the remote.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Try

```
git ls-remote --tags origin
```

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly. But I till have another question. I got these results:  refs/tags/0.1, refs/tags/0.1^{}. Do you know what is the second one?

Comment: Sounds like a separate question entirely.

Comment: @lcb This doesn't answer your question, but if you can add the tag name after origin and it will only list a tag that matches exactly.

Comment: @lcb the answer to "why the duplicate tags" is addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346060/git-tag-why-this-duplicate-tag-in-remotes

Comment: Pass `--exit-code` to `ls-remote` if you want a non-zero status when no tag found, e.g. `git ls-remote --exit-code --tags origin v1.2.3`.

Answer (score 45):

To more precisely answer this question, to check if a **specific tag** is in a **given remote** use:

```
git ls-remote <remote-name> refs/tags/<tag-name>
```

Comment: How do I verify that it’s the same tag as local (i.e., that it points to the same commit)?

Comment: If you are wanting to perform this check in a script, for example during a CI process, you can pass the `--exit-code` option:

`git ls-remote --exit-code <remote-name> refs/tags/<tag-name>`


It will return an exit code of 0 if the tag is in the remote, an exit code of 2 if Git was able to connect to the remote but the tag was NOT present, and presumably an exit code of 1 if it was unable to connect to the remote.


You can then check the exit code and perform your logic based on the result.

Answer (score 8):

For lazy people like me, I used to search for it like this:

On **remote tags**:

```
git ls-remote --tags origin | grep TAG_NAME
```

On **local tags**.

```
git tag -l  | grep TAG_NAME
```

Answer (score -3):

Another way, (from "[git: check if commit xyz in remote repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549479/git-check-if-commit-xyz-in-remote-repo)")

```
git branch -r --contains my_tag

# ==== or with a sha1: =====
git branch -r --contains 2e29022d
```

This will list the remote branches that contain the tag or commit.

The output will look like:

```
origin/my_branch_1
origin/my_other_branch
origin/master
```

Comment: This shows that the commit the tag references is on the remote. It does not test whether the actual tag was pushed to the remote.