# How to update local tags to match remote?

Tags: git, tags

I fixed it for my repo by deleting the local tag and then doing a git fetch. This brought the updated tag.

Is there are "right" way to update tags that may have changed on the remote? This is a simple tag, not signed or anything, created with "git tag "

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Make sure you fetch all the tags (through `git fetch --tags`), to get *all* the tags and not just ones referencing commits reachable from the branch heads.

Those (fetched) tags are [annotated ones (and usually not lightweight)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5348017/6309), and if you add deleted one on the local repo, they will just pop back after the fetch.

However, if you have deleted a lightweight one, then you need to recreate it locally: a lightweight tag isn't *usually* pushed or fetched to/from a remote repo.

Note that starting git 1.9/2.0 (Q1 2014), `git fetch --tags` will fetch everything (like `git fetch`), plus the tags. See "[Does “`git fetch --tags`” include “`git fetch`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608181/6309)".

Again, fetch "everything" means annotated and lightweight (if those lightweight tags were previously pushed).

---

As noted below in [biocyberman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588867/biocyberman)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47197167/6309), if you want to fetch tags from *all* remotes (not just the default remote named '`origin`'), you need to add the [`--all` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#git-fetch---all).

```
git fetch --tags --all
```

Comment: Can you include a reference to this: "a lightweight tag isn't pushed or fetched to/from a remote repo." ? 

I do not find a reference that behavior in the documentation.

Comment: @yucer What i meant (5 years ago) that lightweight tag are not meant to be pushed/pulled: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag "Annotated tags are meant for release while lightweight tags are meant for private or temporary object labels. For this reason, some git commands for naming objects (like git describe) will ignore lightweight tags by default."

Comment: @yucer For example: git push doesn't push any tag. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push: But `git push --follow-tags`? It only pushes missing *annotated* tags. Not lightweight. By design.

Comment: As a matter of fact, lightweight tags are fetched from a remote repo. (A simple `git fetch` is enough.) And fetched tags are exactly what they are on the remote: either lightweight or annotated. (git version 2.7.4)

Comment: @RobertSiemer I agree. Technically, you can push/fetch lightweight tags. Lightweight tags are more designed for local usage though.

Comment: `git fetch --tags` also gets lightweight tags, if they were pushed of course ; I think the answer shouldn't say that they are not fetched by `git fetch --tags`

Answer (score 76):

Previous to git 2.30, the right way seemed to be:

```
  git fetch origin --tags --force
```

You should avoid to have *a branch with the same tag name*, because the checkout prioritizes the branch and you can feel like the tag was not updated. Maybe git should have a warning in this case, something like:

> You have updated a tag that differs now from a branch of
> the same name. The reference to "tagname" became ambiguous.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. If the tag has *moved*, everyone needs to use --force to update their local copy.

Comment: Well, I'm fairly certain that was true when I wrote that comment about 4 months ago when I was using an older Git version, but now on Git 2.30 it doesn't appear to be true anymore. Either that or my test was flawed. Someone moved a tag that I had already fetched, and this command no longer moves it for me locally.

Comment: I also  get the same behavior @TTT , and I was also sure that it worked. I will edit the answer. Thanks

Comment: So this is funny. After further testing I realized my test was flawed. I was actually wrong about which commit the remote tag was pointing to. (I had it backwards.) When I ran this command from the other machine it did work and updated it (along with a bunch of others that were out of sync). So this does still work. I was using 2.30.1 for this test. Now I'm curious how you were able to confirm my flawed test? :)

Comment: For even versions greater than 2.30 (v2.37.0 in my case), this seemed to be the correct way to update tag.

Answer (score 12):

What you have said is the right way and that is what the `git tag` manual recommends ( actually, it says, don't change the tags on the remote repo unless the world is coming to an end):

```
git tag -d X
git fetch origin tag X
```

Comment: @flybird yea not a great idea but sometimes we make mistakes or rushed decisions so clean up the remote and delete all local tags with  `git tag -l | xargs git tag -d` then fetch them `git fetch --tags` again I think best not to change so be careful when setting. 

A Lot of people seem to like the drupal guide at https://www.drupal.org/node/1015226

Comment: I can not find a reference to this "don't change the tags on the remote repo unless the world is coming to an end" in the manual.

Can you give the exact reference ? I would like to read more about this problem.

Comment: That reference is in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#_on_re_tagging, in case this is still a question 4.5 years later. :D

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a bug. Though you shouldn't change tags, if one changes upstream, this will update the tag on your repo:

```
git fetch origin "+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*"
```

Answer (score 3):

In fact **`git fetch --tags`** is enough to let git overwrite lightweight and annotated tags by remote tags of either kind. You can consider it a documentation bug for not mentioning that.

Local tags with names which have no equivalent on the remote will be left alone with this command.

<sub>Tested with git version 2.7.4.</sub>

Comment: In git v2.23.0 passing just `--tags` will not overwrite local tags. I have to add `--force` to it.

Answer (score 3):

In case one has multiple upstreams:

```
git --version
git version 2.11.1 
git fetch --tags --all
```

without the `--all` option, I could not fetch the tags from the upstream whose name is not "upstream".

Answer (score 2):

Short cheat sheet with example below for tag `XTAGX` and commit ID `339f42b` to whom, who are using tags only to mark specific commits for yourself (it might be okay to do re-tagging) and not for an opened to wide audience releases. Otherwise it is not good idea and @dannysauer already put a [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#_on_re_tagging) with great explanation and use case.

```
remove locally: git tag -d XTAGX
remove on remote: git push -d origin XTAGX
create locally: git tag -a XTAGX -m "My XTAGX git tag" 339f42b
push to remote: git push origin --tags
list locally: git tags --list
list on remote: git ls-remote --tags origin
additional check to see tags in all history: git log --oneline
```

Good reference with explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5480292/2957102