# How to check tags in all repos

Tags: git, repository

I am using git and repo. After merging something i always push tags.
   Is there any way i can confirm that the tag which i have pushed is present in all repos. Is there any script which can do same??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`git ls-remote --tags <repository>`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote), as shown in  "[Get last git tag from a remote repo without cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12704727/6309)".

You would need to repeat that command for all the remote repos you want to check.
And you will need to filter the result in order to [exclude unreferenced tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5346060/6309).

Comment: but what if i have two branches?? suppose A and B are two branches if i run this command it will show me all the tags present on A and B.. But how to confirm that the particular tag is present on branch A and not on B..

Comment: @mr.attitude http://stackoverflow.com/a/15806668/6309 could help, but there is a limit to what you can check on a remote without a proper clone.

Comment: @mr.attitude tags are not branch specific

Comment: @user1615903 tags reference commits which can be part of one or several branches though.

Comment: thanks VonC for this usefull info.. just last question how do i know on which branch pericular commit/SHA present??

Comment: @mr.attitude that would be `git branch --contains tag` (as mentioned in my previous comment above, which referenced http://stackoverflow.com/a/15806668/6309), but I don't think you can use that command without cloning the repo first, which isn't what you want.