# How to remove refs which ends with ^{}

Tags: git

```
git ls-remote --tags
```

> 2760f6783bf8d8abf77c9fa965acfe27c82b79d4        refs/tags/crashlytics/0.1.0-01
>   e8520c208c64fa5d8b9d8e93418e09bfc7e70f22        refs/tags/crashlytics/0.1.0-01^{}
>   fff5becea9368f01f3ed0419e19c7c51c337e5c7        refs/tags/crashlytics/0.1.0-02
>   9a72878bce84d053ec5fa8d13459f5856e0c8231        refs/tags/crashlytics/0.1.0-02^{}
>   4c0d770f84e8e16508865ef596624b5f1978bd6c        refs/tags/crashlytics/0.2.0-01
>   6c5a2fdfde516aaa45f4f90e22800122acd7d5af        refs/tags/crashlytics/0.3.0-01
>   cf5b8afcf428857e844ae0061f4d75cf4241617b        refs/tags/crashlytics/0.4.0-01
>   f4ff80ad8316cfce57504da94dafc1e1fb106717        refs/tags/crashlytics/0.4.0-01^{}
>   7785ac9fe979a57293153612868ff7984d42d91a        refs/tags/crashlytics/0.4.1-01
>   fec37e2de5e7ac4941373c522133bfbb930ff431        refs/tags/crashlytics/0.5.0-01
>   17455956d99881a985882a1b70a3e1a078f007a4        refs/tags/crashlytics/0.6.0
>   32beb4e9a9b7505b25d65451668aedd78773895e        refs/tags/crashlytics/0.7.0

I have a lot of refs which ends with **^{}**.

Main question: How to remove them?

Additional: What does that mean?

Data from *packed-refs*

```
2760f6783bf8d8abf77c9fa965acfe27c82b79d4 refs/tags/crashlytics/0.1.0-01
^e8520c208c64fa5d8b9d8e93418e09bfc7e70f22
fff5becea9368f01f3ed0419e19c7c51c337e5c7 refs/tags/crashlytics/0.1.0-02
^9a72878bce84d053ec5fa8d13459f5856e0c8231
4c0d770f84e8e16508865ef596624b5f1978bd6c refs/tags/crashlytics/0.2.0-01
6c5a2fdfde516aaa45f4f90e22800122acd7d5af refs/tags/crashlytics/0.3.0-01
cf5b8afcf428857e844ae0061f4d75cf4241617b refs/tags/crashlytics/0.4.0-01
^f4ff80ad8316cfce57504da94dafc1e1fb106717
7785ac9fe979a57293153612868ff7984d42d91a refs/tags/crashlytics/0.4.1-01
fec37e2de5e7ac4941373c522133bfbb930ff431 refs/tags/crashlytics/0.5.0-01
17455956d99881a985882a1b70a3e1a078f007a4 refs/tags/crashlytics/0.6.0
32beb4e9a9b7505b25d65451668aedd78773895e refs/tags/crashlytics/0.7.0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ^{} mean in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938972/what-does-mean-in-git)

Comment: @Makoto, thank you, but you provided answer for additional question, main is still opened.

Comment: I suppose the question I'd have to ask for context is, why do you want to remove them?

Comment: I'm able to solve my current problem by provided information, but still want to know how to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the same objects. Such references are created when you create an annotated tag.

The `^{}` is a tag dereferencing syntax. It tells to read references until a non-tag object is met. So `tagname` refers to the tag object itself, and `tagname^{}` - to the underlying non-tag object.

You can not delete `tagname^{}` without deleting `tagname`.

See also: [Git tag, Why this duplicate tag in remotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5346060/2790048)